# Android sort arrays

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array in alphabetical order (by word string). After I put this line `Arrays.sort(word, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`, the other parallel string arrays such as example and flag don't match with word position anymore.

If `word string` changes its position after it is sorted, the others strings should be linked to it and change their position.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    ListView list;
    SearchView mSearchView;

    ArrayList<Vocabulary> vocabularylist;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    String[] definition;
    String[] word;
    String[] example;
    int[] flag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        // Generate sample data into string arrays
        word = new String[] { "bimbo", 
                  "heartthrob",
                  "good-for-nothing"};

        definition = new String[] { "loira burra", 
                                    "arrasa-corações",
                                    "vagabundo"};

        example = new String[] { "She's a real bimbo.", 
                                 "He's a real heartthrob.",
                                 "What are you doing wasting time here? Get a job, you good-for-nothing!"};

        flag = new int[] { R.drawable.bimbo, 
                           R.drawable.heartthrob, 
                           R.drawable.vagabundo};

        **// THE PROBLEM IS HERE**          
            **Arrays.sort(word, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);**
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        vocabularylist = new ArrayList<Vocabulary>();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            Vocabulary vocabulary = new Vocabulary(word[i], definition[i], example[i],
                    flag[i]);
            vocabularylist.add(vocabulary);
        }

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), vocabularylist, word, definition, example, flag);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

         list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
         setupSearchView();
        // Capture ListView item click
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data definition

                Vocabulary voc = (Vocabulary) adapter.getItem(position);

                i.putExtra("definition", voc.getDefinition());
                // Pass word
                i.putExtra("word", voc.getWord());
                // Pass example
                i.putExtra("example", voc.getExample());
                // Pass flag
                i.putExtra("flag", voc.getFlag());
                // Pass position
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false); 
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Pesquise aqui...");
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an object that stores all the data collectively from the arrays called `Vocabulary` and your adapter is using a list of those objects that you have already created.

All you need to do is sort the `vocabularyList` as follows:

```
Collections.sort(vocabularyList, new Comparator<Vocabulary>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Vocabulary lhs, Vocabulary rhs) {
        return lhs.getWord().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getWord());
    }
});
```

You can add this just before assigning the adapter its value.

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), vocabularylist,
                              word, definition, example, flag);
```

Also, the adapter should only need the `vocabularyList` since that list contains the information from the arrays `word`, `definition`, `example`, and `flag`. You should remove those from the `ListViewAdapter` if they are not used in it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining multiple arrays that must be associated in a order after sorting, create a class with all the attributes you need (definition, words ans example ), define ONE list with that object type and sort it by the desired criteria

At the end of the sortime you will get concordance with all the membersame in the list

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a class and implement comparable interface:

```
public class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
   String definition;
   String word;
   String example;
   int flag;

  public int compareTo(Data data)
  {
     return this.word.compareTo(data.word);
  }
}
```

and instead of defining word, example,... define an array of Data:

```
Data[] dataArray;
```

and use:

```
Arrays.sort(dataArray);
```

now all of the indexes are linked together

Comment: I defined a class Data and implemented comparable interface. Then I updated my MainActivity put `Data[] dataArray;` and `Arrays.sort(dataArray);` as you will see above. But something went wrong. My application is stopped and finished. Take a look my updated post above!

Comment: you didn't put any data in dataArray. It is null

Comment: yeah, I tried to put this `dataArray = new Data[] { "bimbo", "loira burra", "she's a real bimbo", R.drawable.bimbo};` but a red mark shows with the msgerror: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String  to Data

Comment: that's not how it works. dataArray = new Data[]; dataArray[0].word = bimbo;dataArray[0].flag = ....